# Will an ssd make the ubuntu UI more responsive?

Tags: hard-drive, gui, ssd, responsiveness

I apologize if this is a duplicate, if it is I was not able to find any actual explanation with Google or Bing or even searching Ask Ubuntu.

I want to know if an SSD will improve the Ubuntu UI or KDE desktop. I know that I/O and loading times will be a *ton* faster than what I had on a 5200 rpm, 250 GB hard disk with disk surface problems, but is there any way I can use it over a hard drive to make the Ubuntu UI consistently more responsive? I want to know if it will solve some, if any, of the stuttering I got on my system before the hard drive failed almost altogether.

I'm asking this on Ask Ubuntu just because on Mac, an SSD seemed to do nothing to UI responsiveness, while on Windows, adding a swap drive helped a bit with keeping programs running just fine under heavy multitasking but also really helped with keeping the UI smooth on Vista and later in the form of a large pagefile on a small 8 GB eSATA drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processor, memory and video cards have major impact on UI responsiveness, an SSD will only improve boot speed and program launch times.

A better solution would be to use a lighter DE, like XFCE.

Comment: An SSD will improve responsiveness, if main memory is a bottle neck. In that case it's more efficient and effective to increase the amount of main memory though.